# Which weapons provide the ripe-watermelon head explosion animation?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I was showing off the game to my brother the other day and I whipped out the sniper rifle and sorta hurt someone.  After hyping it up a bit, it was unimpressive to say the least.

Well, I reloaded, switched back to my usual rifle and splatter ensued for an appreciative audience.

Which weapons give the head splatter/headless corpse effect or is it a function of the amount of damage delivered? (or something else altogether?)

[image: Gah!]

Comment: This isn't just sniper rifle specific (I can pull it off with mah Carnifax also) You might change it to consider all weapons.

Comment: I think it's just Heavy Pistols, Shotguns and Sniper Rifles. Not sure if slow fire ARs do it or not

Comment: @BenBrocka At least one Sniper Rifle failed to do it, that's why I thought I'd ask

Comment: Was it the Incisor? May simply be based on damage inflicted in the killing blow

Comment: You can splatter whole bodies too.  I've done it with the Black widow to Cerberus Troopers with less than 25% health left.

Comment: @BenBrocka I think it might have been the Viper.  It had a decent capacity which is why I took it for a spin in the first place.

Comment: @BenBrocka: I think I was able to do it with a Mattock once or twice, but it's been a while since that particular mission.

Comment: @CaulynDarr Carnage definitely does the whole-body gib effect, I wasn't sure if any weapons did

Comment: with the M-98 Widow pretty much every head shot creates the splatter effect for me.

Comment: Mattock does it pretty consistently for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most weapons will get the animation, but some will actually not show it.

Any sniper rifle, Carnifex, Phalanx, Claymore, Graal, Saber, Paladin, Eviscerator, and Wraith. Those have the highest chances of doing so.